# Aggregate Wildcard Search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wanting to return a list that match a string, so when I type in a cell, it will bring back a list of 10 possible matches.

I have tried using the aggregate, but it's fixed, and I need a wildcard

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$26,AGGREGATE(15,3,($A$2:$A$26=$X$3)/($A$2:$A$26=$X$3)*(ROW($A$2:$A$26)-ROW($A$1)),ROW(1:1)),0)
```

I am needing it to list all the rows that have that character

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$C$2&"*",$A$2:$A$10)),ROW($A$2:$A$10),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Hi JvdV, That is exactly what I'm after but I'm needing it to work with Online Excel 365

Comment: Then you would simply use his isnumber(Search()) in the aggragate: `=INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,3,ROW($A$2:$A$26)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$C$2&"*",$A$2:$A$10))),ROW(1:1)),0)` @kire38

Comment: I Use this for Vertical: `=INDEX($A$4:$A$9,AGGREGATE(15,3,ROW($A$4:$A$9)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$C$4&"*",$A$4:$A$9))-(ROW($A$4)-1),ROW(A1)))`

Comment: I Use  this for Horizontal: 
 `=INDEX($A$4:$A$9,AGGREGATE(15,3,ROW($A$4:$A$9)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$C$4&"*",$A$4:$A$9))-(ROW($A$4)-1),COLUMN(A1)))`